# Show select option based on previous select value

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

How do I display a select option based on a previously selected value in Angular select?

Please refer the below code, here I am trying to conditionally display select option (Target 1/Target 2) based on the selected value from the source select.

***component.html***

```
<clr-select-container>
<label>Source</label>
<select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.primary" name="primary" required>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
</clr-select-container>

<clr-select-container>
<label>Target 1</label>
<select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.secondary" *ngIf="formData.tierTwo.primary === 'Apple'" name="secondary" required>            
    <option value="Apple is selected">Apple Option 1</option>
    <option value="Apple is selected">Apple Option 2</option>
</select>
</clr-select-container>

<clr-select-container>
<label>Target 2</label>
<select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.secondary" *ngIf="formData.tierTwo.primary === 'Orange'" name="secondary" required>            
    <option value="Orange is selected">Orange Option 1</option>
    <option value="Orange is selected">Orange Option 2</option>
</select>
</clr-select-container>
```

How do I handle the above select conditionally based on first select value.

***component.ts***

```
formData = {
    tierOne: {
      dataOne: '',
      dataTwo: '',
    },
    tierTwo: {
      primary: '',
      secondary:'',
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering to show the checkboxes based on previous values:

```
<clr-select-container>
<label>Source</label>
<select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.primary" name="primary" required>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
</clr-select-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="formData.tierTwo.primary === 'Apple'">
  <clr-select-container>
    <label>Target 1</label>
    <select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.secondary" name="secondary" required>            
      <option value="Apple is selected">Apple Option 1</option>
      <option value="Apple is selected">Apple Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </clr-select-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="formData.tierTwo.primary === 'Orange'">
  <clr-select-container>
    <label>Target 2</label>
    <select clrSelect [ngModel]="formData.tierTwo.secondary" name="secondary" required>            
      <option value="Orange is selected">Orange Option 1</option>
      <option value="Orange is selected">Orange Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </clr-select-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Tried this but target 1 or target 2 do not show up even after I select an option on source select.